# Return full object matching filter with JsonPath

Tags: jsonpath

I am using the jayway JsonPath library in Java and am trying to see whether a specific JSON object matches a particular filter. If it matches, I want to return the **entire JSON object** but if it doesn't I want to return NULL. In effect, this is the SQL equivalent of a `select * from blah where ...` statement. My objects look something like this:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "SenderCompID": "ABC",
        "TargetCompID": "DEF",
        "MsgType": "BN",
        // ... More here ...
    },
    "Body": {
       "QuoteReqID": "QID1234_ABC_DEF",
       "NoRelatedSym": [{
          "Symbol": "ZZZ",
          "Size": 12345
          // ... Etc. etc. ...
       }]
    },
}
```

I would like to evaluate a JsonPath expression like: `$[?(@.QuoteReqID =~ /QID123/)]` such that I am returned the full object (with Header and Body) when QuoteReqID (or some other fields) match my expression. Is this possible?

Thanks!